# When Serilog [NotLogged] attribute is applied to NetworkCredential object

Tags: serilog

Given the following class, how do I suppress the Credentials property from being logged by Serilog?

```
public class SmtpConfigInfo
{
    public string SmtpHostName { get; set; }

    public int Port { get; set; }

    [NotLogged]
    public System.Net.ICredentialsByHost Credentials { get; set; }
}
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to suppress only the "Password" property of Credentials. If not, it's acceptable for me to see the whole Credentials being suppressed for now. However, when I log with Serilog as follows,

```
seriLogger.Error("{@ConfigInfo}", MySmtpConfigInfo)
```

the [NotLogged] attribute is ignored and I see all properties of Credentials including UserName and Password in the clear. I saw a documentation that seems to indicate that if my Credentials property were broken down to UserName and Password properties, then applying [NotLogged] to Password could work. Is that the only option I have using "Serilog.Extras.Attributed"?
Thanks much!

Answer (score 4):

To enable the `NotLogged` attribute you need to add `.Destructure.UsingAttributes()` - if this is missing the attribute will be ignored.

Example:

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Destructure.UsingAttributes()
    .CreateLogger();
```

Alternatively, the long-form solution is something like:

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Destructure.ByTransforming<SmtpConfigInfo>(info => new {
        info.SmtpHostName,
        info.SmtpPort,
        Credentials = new { UserName = info.Credentials.UserName }
    })
    .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: I am a little confused by the answer. You say you need `.Destructure.UsingAttributes()` but then that doesn't appear in the code.

Comment: Apologies- they're two different solutions; you can apply the `.Destructure.UsingAttributes()` configuration and `[NotLogged]`, _or_, you can use the "long form" `.Destructure.ByTransforming()` code above. Cheers!

Comment: I am using Serilog v2.5.0 and also refering Destructurama.Attributed. But "new LoggerConfiguration().Destructure.UsingAttributes()" is throwing compile time error. like ''LoggerDestructuringConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'UsingAttributes' and no extension method 'UsingAttributes' accepting a first argument of type 'LoggerDestructuringConfiguration' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'. Please Help

Comment: @Raghu The attribute destructuring support in Serilog has been moved to the `Destructurama.Attributed` project (https://github.com/destructurama/attributed). In addition to this, a lot of the newer features have not yet been released as an official version bump of the current nuget package, which means you'll need to check 'include prerelease` in the nuget UI in VS.